Will react-19's "use" hooks replaces tanstack query package?
Will react-19's "use" hooks replaces Tanstack query package?

I know, the use won't be doing all the things which Tanstack query package brings to table, still posting this question still to understand the future plans on both sides.
I feel, this is similar to useReducer hook which is useful but Redux is used for full set of capabilities and DX.
